# WordPress Gutenberg block template columns with RangeControl

Tags: wordpress, block, wordpress-gutenberg

i have the following code:

```
    const BLOCKS_2COL_TEMPLATE = [
    ['core/columns', {
        columns: 2,
        className: "row",
    },
        [
            ['core/column', {
                className: "col-md-6",
            },],
            ['core/column', {
                className: "col-md-6",
            },],
        ]
    ],
];
```

That works fine. But if I select my block content, I have the option to select more columns via the RangeControl field. How can I prevent this?

Smething like this:

```
['core/columns', {
    columns: 2,
    className: "row",
    RangeControl: {
        min: 2,
        max: 2,
    }
},
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: maybe you don't need columns, if you won't enable the user to choose a count of columns?

Comment: if i remove the "['core/column', {" how can i add classes to the single columns in the edit field?